# setState express not as usual

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am reading the react docs and could not understand this code:

```
handleFahrenheitChange(temperature){
    this.setState({
        scale:'f',
        temperature
    });
}
```

Why is it only 'temperature'? It changes what? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

In ES6 syntax you can use

```
{ temperature }
```

to represent

```
{ temperature: temperature }
```

It doesn't have anything to do with React at all.

Answer (score 0):

Temperature is an es6 enhanced object literal

http://www.benmvp.com/learning-es6-enhanced-object-literals/

Answer (score 0):

**Temperature is an ES6 enhanced object**

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html